# Hibernate cannot find Persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a web app i created with Hibernate in Netbeans. I can't run my app because of classpath issues. It can't find my persistence.xml file. this is the project's folder structure in Netbeans:

```
Web pages
  - META-INF
     - persistence.xml
  - Web-INF

Source packages
  - <default package>
     - persistence.xml
com.company.me
  - java source files 
  = (One of the files contains the main() method that i am using to run
     the app. I am not running the project as web app but rather as normal app using the main() method as entry point)
```

You can see that `persistence.xml` is in two places. I just put them there to test if it will find them. I read from some other posts that the `persistence.xml` must be in `src/main/resources`, I have tried to create that folder structure but it didn't work and put the `META-INF/persistence.xml` there but it didn't work.

I have also tried to create the same folder structure on the file system but it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in `WEB-INF/classes`. That's the root of the classpath for a web application.